# Where can I find a NLTK source + installation?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, nltk-trainer

I found a helpful NLTK guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-perform-sentiment-analysis-in-python-3-using-the-natural-language-toolkit-nltk

However, it does not meet my criteria. I need a deeper analysis. Does anyone have a good NLTK source and how to install it so I can add it to my NLTK classifier?

Comment: Also, sources in other languages

Answer (score 1):

You can review these sites. I hope these sites are useful for you.

1. [nltk book](https://www.nltk.org/book/)
2. [Analticsvidhya](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/sentiment-analysis-using-nltk-a-practical-approach/)
3. [github examples](https://github.com/hb20007/hands-on-nltk-tutorial)